# Segmentation error in Xcode, debugger cant help me

Tags: c, xcode, segmentation-fault

I have been going crazy trying to figure out what is done wrong. I admit I am inexperienced when it comes to C, but I don't know what is wrong. Is the way that I am accessing/using the struct incorrect?

EDIT: I keep getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in debugger.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_STRING 20
#define MAX_PLYR 16

typedef struct {

        char pname[MAX_STRING];
        int runs;
        char *s;

} Team_t;

int
main(void) 
{
        Team_t *team_data[MAX_PLYR];
        int i;
        char *p;
        char name[MAX_STRING];
        FILE *inp;
        inp = fopen("teamnames.rtf", "r");

        for (i = 0; i < MAX_PLYR;) {
            while ((fgets(name, MAX_STRING, inp) != NULL));
            printf("Name(i): %s\n", name);
            strcpy(team_data[i]->pname, name);
            i++;
        }
        fclose(inp);
        return(0);
}
```

Edit: Here's what's changed, still getting Segmentation Error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_STRING 20

#define MAX_PLYR 16


typedef struct {

char pname[MAX_STRING];
int runs;
char s;

} Team_t;

int
main(void) 

{
Team_t team_data[MAX_PLYR];

char name[MAX_STRING];

int i;

FILE *inp;

inp = fopen("teamnames.rtf", "r");

for (i = 0; i < MAX_PLYR; i++) {

    ((fgets(name, MAX_STRING, inp)));

    if (feof(inp)) {

        printf("End of stream\n");

        i = MAX_PLYR;

    }

    else {

        if (ferror(inp)) {

            printf("Error reading from file\n");
}

    printf("Name(i): %s\n", name);

    strcpy(team_data[i].pname, name);
}
}

fclose(inp);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you check `fopen` for the return status, files do not always open successfully

Comment: why do people always mix tabs with spaces -.- makes it really hard to reformat and to understand if the editor has the wrong spacing.

Comment: The `while` loop inside the `for` loop will cause problems. Either you read a fixed amount of items from the file (like in the `for` loop), or you read all of them until the end of the file (like in the `while` loop), but trying to combine them will not work the way it should. Especially not, if there's a `;` preventing a body for the `while` loop.

Comment: made all of these edits and none change the error

Answer (score 0):

You declare `team_data` but you don't allocate it; therefore it's pointing off into random memory, as are the imaginary contents of the array. You need to actually create the array, something like

Team_t *team_data[MAX_PLYR] = (Team_t**) malloc(MAX_PLYR * sizeof(Team_t *));

Comment: Should i remove the * from team_data. I apologize for my not understanding but I am VERY new to C

Comment: Yes, as several other posters have recommended, you could get rid of the pointers and declare this as `Team_t team_data[MAX_PLYR]`.  This changes the syntax you use to access the elements: generally you'd use a `.` instead of a `->`.

Answer (score 0):

Use structs, not pointers (or if you insist using pointers the allocate space for those structs)

```
Team_t team_data[MAX_PLYR];

fgets(team_data[i].pname, MAX_STRING, inp)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you write

```
 Team_t *team_data[MAX_PLYR];
```

you are not allocating any memory for the actual Team_t records, instead you are setting up an array of pointers to records.

If instead you would write

```
Team_t team_data[MAX_PLYR];
```

you would have allocated the records. When you then want to copy into the team_data array you write instead

```
strcpy( team_data[i].name, name );
```

Comment: I have allocated records as you suggested, there is no change to the error.